# how can I pass arguments to keydown event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function inside that I will call

```
$document.on('keydown', handleKeyPress);

var handleKeyPress = function (event) {
    var keyCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    // some logic
}
```

But here I want to pass $element as an argument to handleKeyPress.
I have tried this code

```
   $document.on('keydown', handleKeyPress($element, event));
   
   var handleKeyPress = function (element, event) {
      var inputElement = element;
      var keyCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
      // some logic
   }
```

but it's throwing an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at defaultHandlerWrapper (angular.js:3840)......`
Please help me with this, any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
$document.on('keydown', (event) => handleKeyPress($element, event));

var handleKeyPress = function (element, event) {
 // your logic
}
```

Comment: Can I use this `$document.off('keydown', handleKeyPress);` to stop this event.?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use it without any problems